# Rails: ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

*Is it possible* to have the following two columns on an table and save them with active_record:

- `user_name_id` (which is an association)
- `user_name` (just text)

**To demonstrate an attempt to save the association field `user_name_id` and the text field `user_name`**

Here are the models:

```
#app/models/blog.rb
class Blog < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user_name
end

#app/models/user_name.rb
class UserName < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :blogs
end
```

The form:

```
<%= form_for(blog) do |f| %>
  <% if blog.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(blog.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this blog from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% blog.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :user_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :user_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :user_name_id %>
    <%= f.collection_select :user_name_id, UserName.all, :id, :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The strong params:

```
def blog_params
  params.require(:blog).permit(:user_name, :user_name_id)
end
```

When I submit the form in order to create a new `blog`, it errors out. The params hash looks ok:

```
“blog”=>{“user_name_id"=>"1", “user_name"=>”foo”}
```

However I am getting the following error:

> ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch
>   UserName(#70119900697480) expected, got String(#70119800086640)

**Update**: I understand that, ideally: the column name of one of these attributes should change.  Nonetheless: **is it possible** to do this with rails?  What would it take?

Comment: Show the two models, and controller of the blog

Comment: Does the blog belong_to a table called user_name or user?

Comment: belongs to an actual table called user_names

Comment: I agree with gates - post all the info, and include the form

Comment: adding the info now

Comment: @gates added the info.

Comment: @gwalshington added the info

Comment: It's absolutely possible. But, it would take a whole bunch of monkeying around. At which point, you would have to ask yourself why you are so keen on bucking convention. I mean, there is the whole `convention over configuration` thing - the idea of which is to save you from a whole bunch of monkeying around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is obvious from the answers above - change `user_name` attribute to be called something else.

As a very last resort, this might be a bad suggestion, but you could even try to declare which attribute you're using like:

```
class Blog < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user_name, through: :user_name_id
end
```

But again, the reason you're associating the records, is so that you can call user_name at any point, through the association, and get all the information stored there. Meaning, you don't need to store the user_name with the blog... because you already are through the user_name association.

Comment: There is no need of through too ;)

Comment: If you keep both attributes, there is definitely a need to separate them, by declaring which attribute you are associating through. That's why he got the issue in the first place.

Comment: Unfortunately in the app the two table column names cannot be changed in the app. The column with `_id` represents an association (if present) and the one without the `_id` represents a name when it isn't listed in the collection.

Comment: Why can't they be changed? Seems like the 2 choices are: Call one of them something else, or declare which attribute you're associating to user_name in your Blog model.

Comment: I would remove the user_name in the Blog, as it does not make sense to store it there. I would just put user_id in Blog. If I wanted name, I will get it from user table. If the user updates his profile, the blog will have the wrong name lol unless it's handled. And this kind of architecture is against the single source of truth!!!

Comment: @gates see the updated question.  Hopefully it makes it more clear.

Comment: haha, or just remove it ;). @Neil Everyone here is screaming here asking you to remove user_name in Blog table.

Comment: @gates That route does not make sense for the real world application this applies to. To explain that reason: I would have to explain the application.  If it is not possible to save two attributes: `user_name_id` and `user_name` then just say so.

Comment: @Neil - It's not possbile because Blog.user_name is how you call the associated record. I would call 'user_name' something like 'anonymous_user' or something else.

Comment: @Neil I don't know why people use complicated terms like "real world applications", I have already mentioned the disadvantage of taking that approach

Answer (score 1):

1. You should not use 'user_name' field at all if you already use belongs_to 'user_name'.
2. Please do not call Model 'UserName' this is not good, maybe this is UserProfile or just User?
3. Are you sure you want to cache user_name for your blog? If user will change his name it will makes many problems. If you want to cache user_name for blog anyway you can rename column on 'user_name_cached' and updates it on 'UserName' will updates on before_save callback.

UPDATE for authors' update:

`belongs_to :your_new_belons_to_name, class_name: 'NameUser', foreign_key: 'name_user_id'`

Comment: please see the updated question. This was just a quick demo code to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: if you want to safe original 'user_name' method name I think you have to write your own getter/setter method 
`def user name; 
UserName.where(id: self.user_name_id).first || self.user_name;
 end
`

Comment: but in this case you will get strange code behavior: your variables could be an AR object, could be a string

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
belongs_to :user_name
```

ActiveRecord assumes that `Blog` has an attribute `user_name_id` (which it looks like you have - so far, so good). As stated in the [Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference), you also get a setter method, `user_name=` which expects that you're going to pass it a `UserName` instance.

When you do something like:

```
Blog.new(“user_name_id"=>"1", “user_name"=>”foo”)
```

ActiveRecord is expecting `user_name` to be an instance of class `UserName`. But you just passed it a `String`. Which is exactly what the error is telling you.

Also, I agree with Alexey. I don't know why you would persist `user_name` (as a string) on `Blog`. If the class `UserName` has a `name` attribute, then you can always just do something like:

```
blog.user_name.name
```

I also agree with Alexey that `UserName` is a weird class name. Alexey's recommendations on naming are good ones, so please consider them.

Comment: please see the updated question.  This was just a quick demo code to demonstrate the issue.